# What are the sites and links to get a FIDE rating?

Tags: online-chess, fide

I am an active member of Chess.com. Now, I want a FIDE rating. Are there any possibilities that with reference to the Chess.com rating, I can get a FIDE rating? Since I am new to this please provide me a clear suggestion.

Comment: No. You have to play FIDE rated tournaments in order to get a rating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get a FIDE rating based on Chess.com rating.

First you need to join the Fide Online Community, by [registering](https://arena.myfide.net/register) there and then start playing to get your own rating [here.](https://arena.myfide.net/)

Answer (score 6):

Chess.com is a private organization that is not affiliated with FIDE (the World Chess Federation). Also, Chess.com's ratings are based on online play (and so unofficial), whereas FIDE only rates official, over-the-board tournaments. So it is not possible to get a FIDE rating based on Chess.com rating.

You can get a FIDE rating by playing in a tournament that will get rated by FIDE.

Answer (score 4):

You can get official FIDE rating for online play at https://arena.myfide.net/

Comment: IMHO this is more a comment to @overtheboard answer than an answer to the question